# collective.flowplayer - commercial version

Tags: plone, flowplayer

I'm using [collective.flowplayer 3.0rc2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.flowplayer/3.0rc2) and I need to use the commercial version.

Following [official instructions](http://flowplayer.org/demos/commercial/) I tried adding a KEY property in portal_properties/flowplayer_properties and I changed PARAM/SRC with "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.4.swf" (c.flowplayer uses 3.2.4).

Looking at the source of the page I can see the properties been passed but the player gets blocked and it shows only a black box.

Is there a known-good-way or do I have to override something?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: collective.flowplayer properties, in my experience, are not always passed as it should be. Try, for example, to enable "autoplay". It does not work trough properties, I had to set it in the javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. I have reported it on the issue tracker: http://plone.org/products/collective-flowplayer/issues/10/view and contacted the author